# C# DLL App Settings null

Tags: c#, dll, appsettings

After couple of hours reading internet and trying I gave up.
This code gives empty string:

```
private void ReadAllSettings()
    {
        string pwd = Properties.Settings.Default.passwd.Length.ToString();
        Log("Password: "+ pwd);
    }
```

This - zero:

```
private void ReadAllSettings()
    {
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = null;
        string configPath = Path.GetFileName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        ExeConfigurationFileMap map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
        map.ExeConfigFilename = configPath;
        Log(configPath);
        try
        {
            config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex.Message);
        }

        if (config != null)
        {
            Log("NOT NULL");
            Log(GetAppSetting(config, "passwd").Length.ToString());
        }
    }
```

But if using `OpenExeConfiguration` instead of `OpenExeConfiguration`, it ends with:

```
An error occurred loading a configuration file: The parameter 'exePath' is invalid.
```

Parameter name: exePath

Location is fine. Adding ".config" to it or moving config to user's location from ProgramFiles and giving location explicitly changes nothing...

**Values would be seen even if they are default, but not if values are added\changed after compilation.**

Help please. I've read near 15 different answers here, testing EVERY code, I've seen.

Comment: I get     `An error occurred loading a configuration file: The parameter 'exePath' is invalid.     Parameter name: exePath`

Comment: Reading the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.execonfigurationfilemap(v=vs.110).aspx) implies the assembly is an EXE, not DLL. You did read the documentation right?

Comment: It doesn't seem to me, that there is a check for an assembly type. And from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/199441/DLL-with-configuration-file), [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/199441/DLL-with-configuration-file) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/199441/DLL-with-configuration-file) I see, that it is achievable.

Comment: But even if so, why Properties.Settings won't work?

Comment: Difference is, the links, that you have included **does not use** ExeConfigurationFileMap. Also, you have included the same link three times.